# How to get the module handle the coding is running inside in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

A process maybe loaded many `dll`s, is there a way to get the module handle of some dll the code is running inside (not the module handle of current process).

It is easier in C++

```
// a.dll
HMODULE GetCurrentModule() {
  HMODULE hModule = NULL;
  GetModuleHandleEx(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
    (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModule,
    &hModule);

  return hModule;
}

// FreeLibrary in other place
```

In this way, I can get the module handle of `a.dll`. I tried to migrate this method to C#,

```
public const int GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS = 0x00000004;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public extern static Int32 GetModuleHandleExW(UInt32 dwFlags, IntPtr lpModuleName, out IntPtr phModule);

...

// my.dll (managed dll)
private delegate IntPtr MyFuncDelegate();

private static IntPtr GetCurrentModule()
{
  IntPtr hModule = IntPtr.Zero;

  MyFuncDelegate f = GetCurrentModule;
  IntPtr thisFuncAddress = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(f); 
  GetModuleHandleExW(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
    thisFuncAddress,
    out hModule);

  // int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // 126
  return hModule;
}
```

But everytime `GetCurrentModule` was called, it always returned `0x00000000`. Where did I  make a bug?

Comment: Use window dll : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetModuleHandle

Comment: 0 is the correct return value.  Managed code in an assembly gets just-in-time compiled to an arbitrary address in memory, part of what's called "loader heap" in .NET literature.  That machine code is not part of any DLL.  Or in other words, it is not meaningful to try to obtain a module handle for C# code.  It is not obvious at all why you think you need one.

Comment: This bares the question: What are you going to be doing with the module handle?

Comment: @HansPassant I want to use this module handle to construct an activation context to load private dependencies. This module is embedding a `RT_MANIFEST` resource with ID 2. I gave up this idea, but contruct an activation context from manifest.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to use this module handle to construct an activation context to load private dependencies. This module is embedding a `RT_MANIFEST` resource with ID 2. I gave up this idea, but contruct an activation context from manifest.